# Access SQL: Single Character Wildcard Following Textbox

Tags: sql, ms-access, report

I want to generate a report which will show me all the classes of a certain year level. My data goes from years 1 to 12 and the classes go from A to H. So, for example, it starts at 1A and ends at 12H.

I wrote the following SQL code in order to return all classes of a certain year level but i've run into a problem that i knew i would encounter. My code is the following: (note, txtYearLevel is a textbox which the user enters the year level they desire to view the classes of into)

```
SELECT [form classes].[Form Class]
FROM [form classes]
WHERE [form classes].[Form Class] like Forms![navigation form]![navigationsubform].Form!txtYearLevel & "_";
```

^ this returns no results. I thought i should use an approach like this because _ indicates a single wildcard character. (so this would work for single digit year levels and i would write a similar code to take care of double digit year levels)

I also tried:

```
SELECT [form classes].[Form Class]
FROM [form classes]
WHERE [form classes].[Form Class] like Forms![navigation form]![navigationsubform].Form!txtYearLevel & "*";
```

^ This returns results. However, if i were to type in "1" for example, i would get all classes in year 1, 10, 11 and 12.

Essentially i want to find a way to differentiate single digit classes from double digit classes so they do not show up in the search unless i specifically look for a double digit class (by typing in '12' for example).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Access SQL, `?` is the wildcard for a single character, not `_`.

So -

```
SELECT [form classes].[Form Class]
FROM [form classes]
WHERE [form classes].[Form Class] LIKE 
    Forms![navigation form]![navigationsubform].Form!txtYearLevel & "?";
```